# how do I fadeIn each of the inner elements with an opacity of 0 with .delay(x).animate({'opacity':'1'},x);?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade in each of the elements in this div I have as an example. The problem is that I dont know why the animation doesnt change in the inner elements only the parent.

I have used the following jQuery but doesnt work (tried other things too): `jQuery('h1#hideme.welcome__title').delay(100).animate({'opacity':'1'},400); or jQuery('.welcome__title').delay(100).animate({'opacity':'1'},400); or jQuery('#hideme').delay(100).animate({'opacity':'1'},400);`

**I want to use the above lines specifically.**

```
<div class="section_one">
    <div class="welcome_wrapper">
        <div id="" class="welcome__container">
            <div class="welcome">
                <h1  id="hideme" class="welcome__title">Welcome to Dryft</h1>
                <div class="welcome__info">
                    <p >A Boston waterfront restaurant destination with panoramic views of the harbor. Our menu highlights
                                    many
                                    exciting flavors in some of our most classic New England dishes with a focus on fresh seafood and
                                    local
                                    ingredients.</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-theme">
                                Book Event<i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-xs"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#hideme {

  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you not need to simply fade in the `.welcome` class...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working fine. I edited a little for you to check how it goes. I change `hideme` from `ID` to `class` and added it to the 3 `elements` that will be affected (title, text and button). So I setted the `jQuery` in order to make it.

HTML:

```
<div class="section_one">
  <div class="welcome_wrapper">
    <div id="" class="welcome__container">
      <div class="welcome">
        <h1 class="welcome__title hideme">Welcome to Dryft</h1>
        <div class="welcome__info hideme">
          <p >A Boston waterfront restaurant destination with panoramic views of the harbor. Our menu highlights
            many
            exciting flavors in some of our most classic New England dishes with a focus on fresh seafood and
            local
            ingredients.
          </p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn-theme hideme">
        Book Event<i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-xs"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('h1.hideme').delay(100).animate({'opacity':'1'},400);
$('.welcome__info.hideme').delay(400).animate({'opacity':'1'},400);
$('.btn-theme.hideme').delay(700).animate({'opacity':'1'},400);
```

Comment: thx for the help... I havent used jQuery in a while and the problem was that i was using the script animation before the html but I had it after the parent div. So it was only working in the parent.